# What is wrong with the program

Tags: c++

I am getting error for below code:

```
#include "parent_child.h"
#include "child_proces.h"

int main() {

    childprocess::childprocess(){}
    childprocess::~childprocess(){}
     /* parentchild *cp = NULL;
        act.sa_sigaction = cp->SignalHandlerCallback;
        act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
        sigaction(SIGKILL, &act, NULL);
    }*/
    printf("Child process\n");

    return 0;
}
```

> ERROR: child_proces.cpp: In function âint main()â:
>   child_proces.cpp:11: error: expected `;' before â{â token
>   child_proces.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to
>   âchildprocess::~childprocess()â child_proces.h:9: note: candidates
>   are: childprocess::~childprocess() child_proces.cpp:12: error:
>   expected`;' before â{â token

Answer (score 4):

You can't define constructors or destructors or any other methods for that matter inside another function (including `main`).

Move the definitions outside of main, preferably in an implementation file corresponding to `"child_proces.h"` - like `"child_proces.cpp"`.

To get it to compile, you can try:

```
childprocess::childprocess(){}
childprocess::~childprocess(){}

int main()
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the methods outside the `main` function.

```
childprocess::childprocess(){}
childprocess::~childprocess(){}

int main() {}
```

Also, why did you declare the constructor and destructor in the first place if you weren't planning to do anything in them?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "parent_child.h"
#include "child_proces.h"
childprocess::childprocess(){}
    childprocess::~childprocess(){}
int main() {


     /* parentchild *cp = NULL;
        act.sa_sigaction = cp->SignalHandlerCallback;
        act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
        sigaction(SIGKILL, &act, NULL);
    }*/
    printf("Child process\n");

    return 0;
}
```